# How to get the list of Email id configured in outlook using c#?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to get the list of email id configured in outlook along with default email id.
I want to set a default id from the multiple email id which are configured in outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.Diagnostics.Process class` of c# for this purpose.

You need to create [PRF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062.aspx#BKMK_ManuallyEditing) file first.

Then go to commandline option and import the account you want to launch outlook with.

Command For this is as follows:

```
outlook.exe /importprf C:\Path\FileName1.prf
```

Comment: maNamespace = myapp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myapp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
             
                for (int i = 0; i < maNamespace.Accounts.Count; i++)
                {
                    chk_email_Default.Items.Add(maNamespace.Accounts[i + 1].UserName +'-'+ maNamespace.Accounts[i + 1].SmtpAddress.ToString());
                  
                }

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Namespace.Accounts collection in Outlook? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867142.aspx

Comment: maNamespace = myapp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myapp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
             
                for (int i = 0; i < maNamespace.Accounts.Count; i++)
                {
                    chk_email_Default.Items.Add(maNamespace.Accounts[i + 1].UserName +'-'+ maNamespace.Accounts[i + 1].SmtpAddress.ToString());
                  
                }

Comment: Yes,It is working for me with the help of this I am able to get all the configured email id